# Listing functions defined in a "sourced" script?

Tags: bash

I have a very simple bash script `build.sh` which defines - but doesn't invoke - a collection of functions, e.g.

```
#! /bin/bash

create_iptables_log() {
    # do stuff
}

apply_iptables_rules() {
    # do stuff
}
```

The script is then sourced `source build.sh` and the functions are intended to be run from the command prompt.

How can I get a list of the functions that the script has defined?

I am currently grepping the file, e.g.:

```
grep -v '^#' build.sh | grep function
```

but I wondered if there was a "bash" way to list the functions that are present in the bash environment.

Comment: `declare -f` lists all the declared functions.

Comment: @choroba; `typeset -f` has the advantage that it works also, e.g., in `ksh`.

Comment: `grep -oP '^\S+(?=\(\)\h)'   Build.sh`

Comment: @choroba , works great I used `declare -f | grep '()'`  to just show the names , thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `typeset -f` lists the function definitions. (It is supported at least by `bash` and `ksh`.) Use `awk` if you want to post-process the data, e.g. to extract only the function names.

Comment: works, good about cross shell compatibility too!